# ASP.net form not displaying style on index

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an email sign-up form on the index of my website that is inconsistently showing the styles on the form.

When I load the site www.mysweetsite.com the form style **DOES NOT WORK** (on the interior pages it does display correctly)

When I load the site www.mysweetsite.com/default.aspx it **DOES WORK**

Thanks in advance!

```css
.emailz input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
  margin: 2px 5px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  color: $medgray;
  display: block;
}
 
.emailz input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form_holder">
  <input type="text" value="" name="EMAIL" class="emailz" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" textarea {font-size: 16px;} />
  <input type="button" class="blue_btn" onclick="subscribe();" value="Subscribe" id="btn_Subscribe" />
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like a reference issue on your `<link src...`> - can you show us this? maybe do an absolute ref, `<link src='/mycssfolder/mycss.css' />`

Comment: it's definitely the source path issue

Comment: Sure thing, [<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/styles.css" />]

Comment: This code has issues: `<input type="text" value="" name="EMAIL" class="emailz" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" textarea {font-size: 16px;} />`

Comment: what is the `_` in your link source? a folder name?

Answer (score 0):

I've found some mistakes in your code, in the css declaration. I've made some changes to reproduce the css styles.

- Changed `.emailz input[type=text]` to `input[type=text].emailz`.
- Changed `.emailz input[type=text]:focus` to `input[type=text]:focus.emailz`.
- Removed `textarea {font-size: 16px;}`.
- Changed css color `color: $medgray;` to `color: gray;`.

```css
input[type=text].emailz,
 textarea {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
   outline: none;
   padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
   margin: 2px 5px 3px 0px;
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   height: 35px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width: 250px;
   float: left;
   color: gray; /* $medgray */
   display: block;
 }
 input[type=text]:focus.emailz,
 textarea:focus {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
   border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
 }
```

```html
<div class="form_holder">
  <input type="text" value="" name="EMAIL" class="emailz" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" />
  <input type="button" class="blue_btn" onclick="subscribe();" value="Subscribe" id="btn_Subscribe" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone (especially Danny FJB)!!. I'll compile this and report back. Cheers-